# Terminal shows me "Revert currently in progress."

Tags: git, revert

### Problem

**I can't catch what this message on my terminal means to me.**

The time I got this message is when I type `git status`.

```
On branch develop
Revert currently in progress.
  (run "git revert --continue" to continue)
  (use "git revert --skip" to skip this patch)
  (use "git revert --abort" to cancel the revert operation)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

### Why this happened

I am creating an app all by myself. The problem happened when I used `git revert`.
This is an image of my commit of my remote repository.
I'm sorry some characters includes Japanese.

[image]

First, I noticed that something caused a huge problem to my project on commit `[Clean]... (id:0844060)` after `Merge #119`.
Eventually, I decided to do `git revert` so I typed `git revert 463b703` and `git revert e9a31bb`; the former was my mistake though.

After I went back to previous commit, I completed fixing my problem and then I did `git push` again. That has no problems.

However, I just found the above message when I did `git status` after `git push origin develop`.

I just would like you to tell me what happens to me and means. Should I do something to delete message? And what should I have done after `git revert` ?

Thank you very much.

=================              =================             =============

Edit 1
I did `git reflog` and then I got these messages.

```
0478591 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from develop 
to master
b0b58fa (origin/develop, develop) HEAD@{1}: commit: `[Add] Give_Item詳細画面の追
加
0478591 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{2}: checkout: moving from master t
o develop
0478591 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{3}: checkout: moving from develop 
to master
0478591 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{4}: checkout: moving from master t
o develop
0478591 (HEAD -> master, origin/master) HEAD@{5}: commit: [Fix] Gitバグ修正
e9a31bb HEAD@{6}: revert: Revert "[Add]PickUp_Place Delte機能Validation実装"
463b703 HEAD@{7}: revert: Revert "[Clean] コードリファクタリング(destructureing)
"
d3abc8d HEAD@{8}: checkout: moving from develop to master
0844060 HEAD@{9}: checkout: moving from develop to develop
0844060 HEAD@{10}: checkout: moving from master to develop
d3abc8d HEAD@{11}: pull: Fast-forward
5a248fc HEAD@{12}: checkout: moving from develop to master
0844060 HEAD@{13}: commit: [Clean] コードリファクタリング(destructureing)
c038eda HEAD@{14}: commit: [Add]PickUp_Place Delte機能Validation実装
3955b04 HEAD@{15}: commit: [Add] PickUp_List Delteボタン実装
5a22d02 HEAD@{16}: commit: [fix] PickUp_Placeのフィルター修正
```

=================              =================             =============

Edit 2
I did `git status` again. It looks like the message is gone...?

```
user@MacBook-Air-4 [12:17:36] [~/Desktop/my_project/extra_exchange] [master]
-> % git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
user@MacBook-Air-4 [12:17:39] [~/Desktop/my_project/extra_exchange] [master]
-> % git checkout develop
Switched to branch 'develop'
user@MacBook-Air-4 [12:18:21] [~/Desktop/my_project/extra_exchange] [develop]
-> % git status
On branch develop
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

==== ==== ==== ====
Edit3

I did `git push`, this is the result of it.

```
user@MacBook-Air-4 [12:54:04] [~/Desktop/my_project/extra_exchange] [develop]
-> % git push origin HEAD
Enumerating objects: 13, done.
Counting objects: 100% (13/13), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
Writing objects: 100% (7/7), 670 bytes | 670.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 7 (delta 5), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (5/5), completed with 5 local objects.
To https://github.com/Toshiyuki023Hori/extra_exchange.git
   b0b58fa..8951723  HEAD -> develop
user@MacBook-Air-4 [12:54:24] [~/Desktop/my_project/extra_exchange] [develop]
-> % gs
On branch develop
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Comment: Did you say `git revert` without knowing what it does? `git revert` creates a new commit via a patch, and that can generate a merge conflict. It looks like you have such a conflict, and now you are stuck in the middle of the operation. To get out of it, do what the message says; you could just `--abort` as it suggests.

Comment: @matt  @RohanKumar Thank you for suggesting. I did `git revert --abort` but I got another message `warning: You seem to have moved HEAD. Not rewinding, check your HEAD!`. After I did `git revert`, I guess I should have not `git push`... Should I go back to previous commit again?

Comment: Could you please check with `git reflog` what additional steps did you do after `git revert`?

Comment: When you did `git revert 463b703` and `git revert e9a31bb`? Which revert was successful(the one which didn't generate any conflicts)? What do you mean by I went back to previous commit? Do you mean `git checkout 463b703`?

Comment: ah, looks like you had committed conflicts without doing `git revert --continue`(I see this additional `0478591`. I think you should go to the branch where you reverted these commits(I think it's `master`) and try doing `git reset --soft HEAD^` to discard latest commit. This would keep files you changed in index which you can add in `git revert --continue`

Comment: @RohanKumar I just added the result of `git reflog`. If it is alright with you, I would like you to check it. Actually, both revert  `463b703` and `e9a31bb` didn't work well. So, I copied my original project and pasted it to the same directory as original project directory had existed. And then, I did `git push` and a problems was solved. However, this `git` problem came to me instead.

Comment: @RohanKumar I really appreciate your quick help from bottom of my heart. Let me check what I should do before I do that. First, I go back to `master` where I reverted these commits and then I will do `git reset --soft HEAD^`. Second, I will `git revert --continue` in `master` branch. And, I can go back to my develop branch and continue developing like before. Is this correct?

Comment: After copying orignal project directory, did you do commit too?  When I'm trying to reproduce your problem(committing directly without resolving conflict), Git is creating commit resolving the revert. I'm not sure how you're still getting `Revert currently in progress.` I'm using git `2.26.2`

Comment: Could you please share your current `git status` output too?

Comment: @RohanKumar Yes, I did commit right after I complete copying my original project. I am using `2.24.3 (Apple Git-128)`.

Comment: From your `git status` logs, I think `git` resolved revert when you had committed. You can inspect this by checking with `git show 0478591` and see if it contains the changes you wanted to revert

Comment: @RohanKumar I inspected the difference by `git show 0478591`. I think it has all changes what I wanted. Is this problem solved? I just would like to make sure I can do `git push origin HEAD` in my develop branch.

Comment: I thought you already pushed in your previos step. I think the problem is solved. If everything went as expected, you should get `Everything up-to-date
` on `git push`

Comment: @RohanKumar Thank you very much.  You helped me out very much. I did `git commit` and `git push` and then I got a log which I just added to my question. I can't see `Everything up-to-date` on this log but it looks fine, doesn't it?

Comment: If the question is how your branch stands with respect to the remote version of the same branch, `git fetch` and then `git diff develop origin/develop`.

Answer (score 4):

[`git revert`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) tries to reverse the effect of commits specified as an argument. This can be problematic sometimes and can generate [merge conflicts](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/using-branches/merge-conflicts)(when two people have changed same section of some files and git is not sure which change to pick up). If you know about what files you need to change in order to revert the specified commit. You should try to fix conflicts and do:

```sh
git status
...
# Check files pointed out by git for conflicts
# Make changes to files with conflict
git add files/with/conflict
git revert --continue
```

If you're not sure how to proceed and want to revert back to previous state. You need to abort the revert(already suggested in comments):

```sh
git revert --abort
```